# Closing a file descriptor (or a socket) in C

Tags: c, file, sockets

I have a doubt:
when I create a file descriptor with an **fd = open()** or a socket with a **fd = socket()**, and I pass it in a function **function(fd)** that does **close(fd)**, in the main function, **fd** is still available or doesn't it work?
In other words, when I close a file descriptor passed to a function by value, is it closed also for the calling function?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (on Unix systems, POSIX ones, ...) is known to the kernel and to your entire current process. Each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its own file descriptor table and [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

On Linux, you can use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query both the file descriptors and the virtual address space of some process. For the process of pid 1234, use `/proc/1234/fd/` & `/proc/1234/fdinfo/` to understand its file descriptors and their table, and `/proc/1234/maps` & `/proc/1234/smaps` to understand its virtual address space.

So if a called function `close`-s it, you should not use it anymore. Of course, you might reactivate it (with some other `open`, `socket`, `dup` returning it).

Therefore, you need to define, document and explicit conventions about `close`-ing responsibilities (like you do about `free`-ing pointers). Read also about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

In that aspect, `close` is a bit like `free`: it is *invalidating* the value (file descriptor for `close`, pointer for `free`) passed to it. When possible, you could set the file descriptor to -1 (or some other invalid value) after a successful [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), so code `close(fd); fd = -1;` for example. For similar reasons, I also do `free(ptr), ptr = NULL;` when possible.

BTW, I'm supposing a Unix or POSIX (or Linux) system. I don't know Windows, and it has a very different notion of file descriptors and of [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

Comment: FWIW, on Windows you can't `close()` a socket.  You have to use `closesocket()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441815/are-close-and-closesocket-interchangable and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read some documentation on the close() system call, but yes calling close() regardless of 'where' in process, will cause a trap into the kernel and remove access to the fd for the process.  It will not necessarily free up any assets.